# CSV not keeping the format of my column as numbers once VBA changes it

Tags: excel, vba, csv

Will really appreciate your help on this one, I'm running a macro to save a csv data sheet for a site, but is not keeping the format in one column as number, it turns back to General, also have a date one but that one keeps it, any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the part of the code

```
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=vucempath, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    vucemtemplate = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(Vucem).Activate
        Sheets("template").Select
        

    Workbooks(Vucem).Activate
    Range("C2:N" & CountRows).Copy

    Workbooks(vucemtemplate).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
        Columns("J:J").Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
        
    
        
    CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
       
               
    
    Workbooks(vucemtemplate).Close (savechanges = False)  `
```

Comment: CSV is a text file. It does not have a "format". If you open the CSV in notepad you'll see the data is valid in there. Format is something that excel adds (often incorrectly) when opening CSV files

Comment: But there seems to be a problem on how is pasting the information because the web page is rejecting the file, so when i change the column manually to number and delete the decimals, it works

Comment: The concept *format* does not change the real value of the cell. If you apply `0` as format, you are just *hiding* visually the decimals but they are still there!. If you need to get rid of decimals, round the results using functions or VBA. Check ROUND function.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. If I store decimal numbers in column A, then run your formatting and workbooks.close code, it saved as whole numbers without the decimal. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Generally true. But CSV files generally get saved with the data as displayed, so formatting does have an impact on the saved file.

Comment: So I Kept the Pastevaluesandnumberformats, made some changes on the file, removed the rest column formatting and it worked, checked as advised on Notes and seems fine 

Thank you all